# Clearing a group in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

If I have a group of sprites such as:

```
spriteList = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Is there anyway to delete all of the contents of the group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simple: [`pygame.sprite.Group().empty()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.empty) will do it.

**Edit for clarification:**

Since you have a reference to the `Group` object, call `empty()` on that reference, e.g.

```
spriteList.empty()
spriteList.add()
```

Comment: I tried this but when I try to add something to the group after I've emptied it, it returns the error : "exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'"

Comment: How are you trying to add them after you empty the sprite group? `pygame.sprite.Group().empty()` returns `None`, thus if you're doing it like this: `pygame.sprite.Group().empty().add(sprite)` it will not work because you are, in fact, trying to call `add()` on `None`

Comment: I did the`pygame.sprite.Group().empty()` and then on the next line I did `spriteList.add()`

Comment: Oh, well you should call `empty()` on the reference to the `Group` object you want to empty. So, instead, try this: `spriteList.empty()` and then `spriteList.add()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your code, and I have figured out the reason why there would be an error to it:

> exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'

This line of error, is just saying that it can't add the `NoneType` that you left it to add in this line of code -> `spriteList.add()`.

If you want to add sprites, instead of leaving the brackets blank, include between the `()` brackets the name of your container (variable) that holds the sprite like the following example:

```
# The class Key() is being assigned to or labled as key spriteList.add(key)    
Key() = key
```

If that does not help you then probably [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDu8mcAlY4E&t=681s) link could.

This sends you to one of Clear Code's videos that introduces you to a greater understanding of how to use, add and draw sprites to sprite groups, in the overall summary it introduces you to sprites while using pygame.

Comment: Thank you Destroy for proposing this edit. I really appreciate your kind effort to help make it more sufficient.